# regexp with perl, ungreedy not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl, non-greedy

Could somebody explain to me, why this is not working:

```
# echo '"Hello,1" "Hello,2" "Hello,3"' | perl -pe 's/".+?,3"/1/'
1
```

or

```
# echo '"Hello,1" "Hello,2" "Hello,3"' | perl -pe 's/".+?,2"/1/'
1 "Hello,3"
```

My intention was to replace/find only "Hello,3"/"Hello,2", but It seems that the non-greedy modifier (or my brain) is not working as expected.

Comment: Regex engine matches the string from left to right, the `"` matched the first `"`, and `.+?` did its job correctly, matched up to the first `,3"`. What is the expected output, BTW?

Comment: Could you please clarify what the expected output is? `"Hello,1" "Hello,2" 1`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding regular expressions, but actually I'd probably suggest tackling this one a bit differently. If you've a sequence of words to manipulate, I'd suggest using `split`/`join`/`map` to do the manipulation.

I think it scales better, and doesn't trip over on clarity problems with where the pattern matching boundaries lie.

Something like this:

```
my $str = '"Hello,1" "Hello,2" "Hello,3"';

$str = join ( " ", map { s/Hello,[23]/1/r } split ( " ", $str ) );
print $str;
```

Or as a one liner:

```
perl -ape "/Hello/ and $_ = join ' ', map { s/Hello,[23]/1/r } @F"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/"[^"]+,3"/
```

instead. https://regex101.com/r/4rXN4z/1

[image: Narrative]

Comment: Some narrative would help a lot here.

Comment: Well it's better, but still a bit cheap